# sorting data string to int

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
id(int) item(character varying) sort_no(character varying)
1       item-1                  1
2       item-2                  2
3       item-3                  10
4       item-4                  3
```

Now. I want to output:

```
sort_no      item
1            item-1
2            item-2
3            item-4
4            item-10
```

I tried

```
SELECT sort_no, item FROM table ORDER BY sort_no
```

and got undesired results. The output is

```
sort_no   item
1         item-1
4         item-10
.
.
.
```

Note: I don't want to change the datatype of the table. How to do this?

Comment: Your query really should work. Are you sure the rows with sort_no 2 and 3 exist in the table? Could you give more rows which resulted from your query?

Comment: You probably should change your `sort_no` column to int as I guess `_no` stands for 'number' anyway. In its current form (character varying) it will consider ordering like this : 1, 10, 2, 3, ... as that's how you would sort strings (compare to a, aa, b, c, ...) Otherwise, your query looks OK. The only other reason I can think of is that you have leading spaces in the sort_no column that confuse the sorting.

Comment: MySQL, or PostgreSQL, or both? They handle this differently.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysql uyou can use cast to convert the char to integer:

```
SELECT sort_no, item FROM table ORDER BY cast(sort_no as UNSIGNED)
```

See the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

To sort by the column `sort_no` as if it contained integers, you can cast it to integer (in PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT sort_no, item FROM table ORDER BY sort_no::int
```